# Why do I get a type error when looking to GET request a specific article?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, parameters

My code is below... I'm supposed to be able to type articles/DOM and be able to get all objects with the title DOM, but instead, I get a type error that ArticleTitle is undefined. Please help!

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle").get( function(res,req) {

  

  Article.findOne({title: req.params.articleTitle}, function(err,foundArticle){

    if (foundArticle){
      res.send(foundArticle)
    } else{res.send("No article matching that title was found!")}

  });

}

)



app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
  });
```

Comment: What URL are you calling? e.g. `http://example.com/articles/xxxx`?

Answer (score 0):

`first argument` should be `req`, and `second argument` should be `res` so do like this:

```
app.route("/articles/:articleTitle").get( function(req, res) {})
```

Comment: Oh dang!! Lemme try that!